# UWP Mi Band 2 How to take a value from characteriscic

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to interact with my Mi Band 2 via C#. First, i want to take battery level. I already connect my device with band, and i take some values, but i think this not what i need.
[I found uuids of services and characteristics and examples on Java, here](https://github.com/aashari/mi-band-2)

But author can handle received data, i am not.

```
                BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(args.Id);

            // Parse Basic Service by UUID
            var result = await bluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("0000fee0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

            // Parse Battery Info Characteristic of this service
            var characteristic = await result.Services[0].GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("00000006-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700"));
            GattReadResult gattReadResult = await characteristic.Characteristics[0].ReadValueAsync();
            byte[] data;

            // Read received data to byteArray
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(gattReadResult.Value, out data);


            // Just convert it to string. I Receive HEX Value, but i don't know what it mean. It's not battery percentage.
            // 0F-4F-00-E2-07-04-0E-10-27-11-0C-E2-07-04-0E-13-19-16-0C-64
            Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
```

I read in other forums what battery percent saved in first byte (data[0]), but i get wrong number, it's not Battery Level.

byte[] data saves 20 int values. **None of them not Battery Percentage**.

Am i wrong? How i can take Battery level value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your result is absolutely right.
I remembered something like your result and after some fiddling I came up with this:

0F-4F-00-E2-07-04-0E-10-27-11-0C-E2-07-04-0E-13-19-16-0C-64
Read it as:

Status now: 0F-4F-00-E2-07-04-0E-10-27-11-0C

0F  =  ?

4F  =  79  Percentage charge at this moment:

00  =  00  (00 = STATUS_NORMAL, 01 = STATUS_CHARGING)

E2 07 =  Year: 2018 (Swap bytes 07 E2 )

04   =  Month: 4

0E   =  Day   : 14

10   =  Hour  : 16

27   =  Minute: 39

11   =  Second: 17

0C  =  number of charges: 12

Last charge time: E2-07-04-0E-13-19-16-0C-64

E2 07 = Year:   2018 (Swap bytes 07 E2 )

4   = Month:  4

0E  = Day  :  14

13  = Hour :  19

19  = Minute: 25

16  = Second: 22

0C  = number of charges: 12

64  = how much was charged last charge time: 100

Check you device again to see if I had date/time mixed up.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks!